# Python Index filter

Tags: python-3.x, indexing, filtering

I want to ask regarding python index and Data Frame

```
Given DataFrame:
   A    B    C
0  1  NaN    3
1  4    5  NaN
2  7    8    9
```

if we do this: diabetes_data.isnull()
it will:

```
       A      B      C
0  False   True  False
1  False  False   True
2  False  False  False
```

However, this is the part that I dont understand when we index it to the original DF.
diabetes_data[diabetes_data.isnull()]

```
A      B      C
0  NaN   NaN    NaN
1  NaN   NaN    NaN
2  NaN   NaN    NaN
```

I wasn't expecting the result to be converted into NaN. please help to explain the logic or workflow.

what I am expecting is that it will output Df.diabetes_data column that is NaN(missing values)

Comment: What you expected is unclear, can you provide the explicit expected output? Here you're selecting the NaN cells and "convert" the other ones to NaN, it makes sense that the output is all-NaN.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? As output, do you want to get the columns and row index of the values that are NaN (in this case 0,B and 1,C)? Or just the column that doesn't contain any NaN (so all of columns A)?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I dont understant. I mean like I am not really trying to achieve a particular output. I am just trying to understand the logic of diabetes_data[diabetes_data.isnull()]

Comment: @Suksmaid I tried to give a step-by-step explanation below. In summary, what you got is fully expected.

Answer (score 2):

So, the question is "*why do I have this output?*".

Let's take another example:

```
   A  B  C
0  0  1  2
1  3  4  5
2  6  7  8
```

and identify even numbers:

```
df.mod(2).eq(0)

       A      B      C
0   True  False   True
1  False   True  False
2   True  False   True
```

If we use this to index, this will "select" the even/`True` values and display the other ones as `NaN`:

```
df[df.mod(2).eq(0)]

     A    B    C
0  0.0  NaN  2.0
1  NaN  4.0  NaN
2  6.0  NaN  8.0
```

This is usually done to perform boolean indexing to assign a value:

```
df[df.mod(2).eq(0)] = 999
print(df)

     A    B    C
0  999    1  999
1    3  999    5
2  999    7  999
```

Now, in your case you "select" all the NaN values and "hide" the other ones as NaNs, which is why everything now appears as NaN.

If you assign, however:

```
diabetes_data[diabetes_data.isnull()] = 0

print(diabetes_data)

   A    B    C
0  1  0.0  3.0
1  4  5.0  0.0
2  7  8.0  9.0
```